# $\Sigma_0$ formula s.t. $\forall u_1 \dots \forall u_n(\exists v \psi \leftrightarrow \exists v_1 \dots \exists v_k \phi)$ is true in $\mathcal{A}$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{0,S,<,+,\times\}$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the standard model of arithmetic.

Let $\phi(u_1,\dots u_n,v_1,\dots,v_k)$ be a $\Sigma_0$ formula.

> Can we find another $\Sigma_0$ formula $\psi(u_1 \dots,u_n,v)$ such that $\forall u_1 \dots \forall u_n(\exists v \psi \leftrightarrow \exists v_1 \dots \exists v_k \phi)$ is true in $\mathcal{A}$?

Here $\Sigma_0$ means that all the quantifiers are bounded.

I would like to do this from scratch, without relying on any theorems that I haven't learned yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that **bounded quantifiers cost nothing** in arithmetical hierarchy calculations. This means we can cheat wildly: the formula $$\psi(u_1,...,u_n,v)\equiv \exists v_1<v,...,v_k<v\varphi(u_1,...,u_n,v_1,...,v_k)$$ is $\Sigma_0$ if $\varphi$ is $\Sigma_0$. And we have $\exists v\psi(u_1,...,u_n,v)\leftrightarrow\exists v_1,...,v_k\varphi(u_1,...,u_n,v_1,...,v_k)$ in the standard model of arithmetic (set $v=\max\{v_1+1,...,v_k+1\}$).