# Is $(\forall w<u_1)(\exists v) \phi$ equivalent to a $\Sigma_1$ formula?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{0,S,<,+,\times\}$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the standard model of arithmetic.

Let $\phi(u_1,\dots u_n,v,w)$ be a $\Sigma_0$ formula.

> Is $(\forall w<u_1)(\exists v) \phi$ equivalent to a $\Sigma_1$ formula?

Here $\Sigma_0$ means all quantifiers are bounded, and $\Sigma_1$ means there's a string of (not bounded) existential quantifers in front of a $\Sigma_0$ formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. We can just use $$\exists m\forall w<u_1\exists v<m\phi.$$ (My original answer involved coding finite tuples; while that does work, and is an important technique to have at hand, it's massive overkill for this problem as Andreas Blass pointed out below.)

Comment: I still don't understand how to simplify $(\forall w < u_1)( \exists v) \phi$ formally. (For the present purposes, I'm only concerned with $\mathcal{A}$ equivalence)

Comment: Well, you're going to want to whip up a low-complexity relation $t(a,b,c)$ which intuitively says "$a$ is the $b$th term of the sequence coded by $c$." *(You can do this using the $\beta$-function.)* Once you have this, the starting formula $$\forall w<u_1\exists v\phi(w,v)$$ will be equivalent to $$\exists c,d\forall w<u_1\exists k<d[t(k,w,c)\wedge \phi(w,k)].$$ The "$\exists c,d$" meanwhile can be collapsed into a single existential quantifier a la [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407160/sigma-0-formula-s-t-forall-u-1-dots-forall-u-n-exists-v-psi-leftright).

Comment: I never heard of the beta function before, but I looked it up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function and it appears the "$\beta$-function lemma" is what you're alluding to?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Yup, that's it. It's unnecessary if you include exponentiation in the signature, but without exponentiation it's an important trick.

Comment: Instead of coding a finite sequence of witnesses, you could just bound them: $(\exists x)(\forall w<u_1)(\exists v<x)\,\phi$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So $(\forall w < u_1)(\exists v) \phi$ is equivalent to $(\exists x) (\forall w< u_1) (\exists v<x) \phi$? It's really that simple?

Comment: @AndreasBlass ... hehe, whoops. Yes.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager I've edited to use Andreas' vastly simpler approach.